# Removing a cursor in Sublime Text after a find_all search

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I have like 26 cursors after a find_all search, but I want to remove some cursors I wont use.

[image: 5 cursors here on all "lorem"]

I want to be able to remove one of the cursors. Same as <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>LeftClick</kbd> that add a cursor but the inverse of that.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Can you rewrite your question and maybe add a picture to explain what you want?

Comment: Do you want to remove carets with the mouse?

Comment: yes that is what I want

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Subtractive Selection` modifier in conjunction with <kbd>LeftClick Drag</kbd>.

`Additive` & `Subtractive` modifiers can be used with both regular `Selection` & `Column Selection`.

More info @:

## [**Sublime Text Docs / Editing**](http://sublimetextapi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/editing/editing.html)

---

---

## WINDOWS

**Column Selection:**
<kbd>RightClick Drag</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>
OR
<kbd>MiddleClick Drag</kbd>

**Additive Selection:**
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

**Subtractive Selection:**
<kbd>Alt</kbd>

---

---

## LINUX

**Column Selection:**
<kbd>RightClick Drag</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>

**Additive Selection:**
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

**Subtractive Selection:**
<kbd>Alt</kbd>

---

---

## OS X

**Column Selection:**
<kbd>LeftClick Drag</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd>
OR
<kbd>MiddleClick Drag</kbd>

**Additive Selection:**
<kbd>⌘</kbd>

**Subtractive Selection:**
<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>

Comment: It's not working. It does nothing and if I do it in a place where there is no cursor, that does the stuff command + click does.

Comment: @Charlon: What operating system are you on? What command did you try using?

Comment: Weird... I'm on Windows & the listed commands works fine. Try __column selection__ + __subtractive selection__. If that doesn't work, try [__creating your own mouse bindings__](http://superuser.com/questions/923857/change-middle-mouse-button-in-sublime-text).

Comment: This would be pressing all `alt+shift+super` modifiers.

Comment: rather than clicking did you try click and drag? On windows if I have multiple cursors and try to alt + click on one I don't want it usually wipes out all cursors and makes a new one where I clicked. If hold alt and I swipe (from left to right) while clicking to sort of select the one I don't want, then it works great.

Comment: __+1__, as mentioned in the answer - all click actions are click+drag. The entire process is: press & hold modifier(s), click+drag target selections/deselections, release mouse button, release modifier(s)

Comment: alt+shift+super works TY@r-stein !!!!!! :D Can you do an answer so that I'll upvote you ?